# How to prevent elements from have the same offset value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a page with a similar layout to facebook. I have created the two column grid using the Masonry plugin.

Now I am trying to create the little tooltips that facebook has for each post which creates the timeline effect. The problem is that some articles are aligned equally, their tooltips will overlap. Is there a way to check of any two articles have the same top offset (??) and if so add some margin to one of them so that they are not the same.

I tried to illustrate the grid here http://d.pr/i/9MzP - the idea is the green boxes is what I have a problem with, I dont want them to be parallel with each other.

Thanks

Comment: Hey did you find the solution? I can't figure this out.

Comment: @BenjaminNetter I am close to the solution but does not yet to a satisfactory state. Basically I modified the jQuery Masonry plugin to add a left or right class to each div and added an if statement to check if any two (.left and .right) have the same offset. I guess it just needs fine tuning (have not had time to work on it)